# Confused with time and space complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, backtracking

I wrote one backtracking algorithm which resulted in TLE which was obvious.
But I wanted to do the time complexity analysis for it.

I thought that we will make **2N** calls then **2N-1** calls then **2N-2** calls and so on.
Total we make **(2N)!** calls and in each call we use a for loop on **2N** elements

Thus overall time complexity is **2N . (2N)!**

But this code runs with input = 6, but TLEs at input = 7
Putting input as 5 or 6 in the time complexity gives a very large numbers they should also result in TLE. But it's not like that.

**Where am I incorrect in my complexity analysis?**

Question: https://leetcode.com/problems/count-all-valid-pickup-and-delivery-options/

Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int MOD = 1e9 + 7;
    
    long backtrack(int N, int ordersPicked, int ordersDelivered, 
             vector<bool>& picked, vector<bool>& delivered) {
        
        // We have picked and delivered all orders.
        if (ordersDelivered == N) {
            return 1;
        }
        
        long ans = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            // Pick a non picked order
            if (!picked[i]) {
                picked[i] = true;
                
                // Count ways after picking the current order.
                ans += backtrack(N, ordersPicked + 1, ordersDelivered, picked, delivered);
                ans %= MOD;
                
                // Backtracking step.
                picked[i] = false;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            // Deliver a picked but non delivered order
            if (picked[i] && !delivered[i]) {
                delivered[i] = true;
                
                // Count ways after delivering the current order.
                ans += backtrack(N, ordersPicked, ordersDelivered + 1, picked, delivered);
                ans %= MOD;
                
                // Backtracking step.
                delivered[i] = false;
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
    
    int countOrders(int n) {
        vector<bool> picked(n), delivered(n);
        return backtrack(n, 0, 0, picked, delivered);
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. You don't need the `int N` parameter: it's the length of your `picked` and `delivered` array. 2. Setting and resetting `picked[i]` is kinda inelegant. Can you use the stack? For instance, pass the `picked` array by value? 3. The `ordersPicked`  variable is never used. 4. Why the `MOD`? I would use an assert and abort on overflow. 5. What are your `picked/delivered` arrays initialized to? Make taht explicit. 6 As to your actual problem: print out a full trace for the case `n=2`. Then do the same thing with pen and paper. Maybe `n=3` too, but by that case the bug should be clear.

Comment: `(2 * N)!` is the number of orders of operations ignoring the fact that a pickup needs to happen before a delivery. For each pair of pickup and delivery there's exactly 1 of 2 orderings, that are actually possible/considered, so 1 in `2^n` are possible/considered and the complexity should be `O((2n)!/ 2^n)` it's bad nonetheless...

Comment: `MOD 10^9+7` is part of the problem to avoid overflow, if that's what you are referring to @VictorEijkhout

Comment: As for TLE, not a complexity analysis: you do not need to _enumerate_ all valid orderings to _count_ them. As a remote analogy, you needn't iterate through A1 ... A8,  B1 ... B8, and so on till H1 ... H8 to find out there are 8×8 = 64 squares in a chessboard.

Comment: @fabian we don't need to multiple (2n)! with (2n)? As in each operation we do two for loop iterations, so total complexity become `[(2n)! * (2n)] / (2^n)` ??